# What is the name of this package(plugin) in Sublime Text?

Tags: package, sublimetext3, file-extension, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

The feature is, when an user hovers the mouse cursor on a specific word, Sublime Text shows up a small display box with few informations which contain a file extension and a scope name of the word.

I couldn't find this tool on the default sublime text so I believe it is one of the packages made by users and despite an hour of searching with bunch of different keywords on the Package Control, have no clue about this plugin.

What is the name of this package/plugin? I would really like to know.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular feature is not a hover feature; it's being triggered by a key binding. The key for it can be seen in the menu under `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name`

That said, the [ScopeView](https://github.com/OdatNurd/ScopeView) package (disclaimer: written by me) has the functionality to continuously show a scope popup as you move around in the document, if that functionality is desirable.